# Polynomial factors and remainders

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I ran into this question on a standardized test but I'm not sure how to solve it. Is there something that I'm missing?

[image]

Transcribed below:

For a polynomial $g(x)$, the value of $g(x)=-3$. Which of the following must also be true about $g(x)$?

1. $(x+3)$ is a factor of $g(x)$
2. $(x-3)$ is a factor of $g(x)$
3. The remainder when $g(x)$ is divided by $(x-5)$ is $-3$
4. The remainder when $g(x)$ is divided by $(x+5)$ is $-3$

Comment: There would seem to be a typo.  My guess is they meant to say $g(5)=-3$ or possibly $g(-5)=-3$.

Comment: "The value of g(x)=-3" is not a proposition.